# Call different functions using Direct Parameter Access in C

Tags: c++, printf

I recently stumbled upon [this page](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigmil/talks/general_exploitation/format_strings/). And I was particularly interested about the section which dealt with Direct Parameter Access.

I was just wondering if there is any way to execute just one of the functions depending on the value of *n* in the following line:

```
printf("%n$p", func1, func2, func3 .. funcN);
```

where func1,.. have signature as int func1(), int func2(), and so on.. This is a restriction as I might want to have function tha return void too.

In the above line, only the address of the function is printed; The function is not called..

I even tried using the ',' (comma operator) to achieve this; but in that case, **all** the functions in the list will get call, and the result corresponding to the 'n' is printed.

Is there any way to actually execute the function inside printf(..)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do this, rather than just call the function and pass the result to printf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this with printf as printf does not support invocation of function pointer parameters.

But, you can write your own function that does this using stdarg:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void invoke_and_print(unsigned int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);

    int (*fp)(void) = NULL;
    while (n-- != 0)
    {
        fp = va_arg(ap, int (*)(void));            
    }
    va_end(ap);

    printf("%d\n", (*fp)());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not in a single line, but something like:

```
typedef int (*fp)();
fp[] thefuncs = {func1, func2, func3, func4};
printf("%d", fp[n]());
```

seems to be a start.  If the functions return void, rather than int, what are you thinking of printing?

Comment: Yes! this way you can achieve that goal! But my question is how can I do that using Direct Paramter access..

Comment: The answer to that is: no, you can't make `printf` invoke functions for you.  Why do you care about "direct parameter access"?  It's not something magical, and even if `printf` could do what you wanted, it wouldn't be any more efficient or more readable than the above solution.